# Don't understand how planet notation works

Tags: uiua

I really don't get what how `×⋅⊙⋅∘ 1 2 3 4` is getting what it does from the stack.

The documentation isn't too clear on it.

Answer (score 1):

So in the example above: `* dip gap dip id 1 2 3 4`

It's important that it ends with a non modifier like `id` (or some other function) because otherwise the penultimate modifier would error).

Modifiers oddly enough need to be read from left to right. So:

- `gap` throws away the `1`
- `dip` temporarily pops the `2` but will return it when we're done
- `gap` throws away the `3`
- `id` keeps the `4`
- the `2` is put back

We end up with `* 2 4` which evaluates to `8`.

It gets somewhat more interesting with a `fork` added in the mix like this:
`⊃(⋅⋅∘)(×⋅⊙⋅∘) 1 2 3 4`.

The maximum of the arms of the `fork` determines the number of stack elements that need to be there (in this case 4) but because the left one only needs three, the last element is thrown away (don't ask me why, but it's pretty essential).

So to work through this case.

Left arm(`(⋅⋅∘)`):

- `gap` throws away the `1`
- `gap` throws away the `2`
- `id` keeps the `3`
- the `4` isn't explicitly addressed, so it's discarded in this arm

The result is `3`.

Right arm(`(×⋅⊙⋅∘)`):

- `gap` throws away the `1`
- `dip` temporarily pops the `2` to return later
- `gap` throws away the `3`
- `id` keeps the `4`

The result is `* 2 4` which evaluates to `8`.